# If one tool of the kit is intended to be used in another one, then the description should have a reference to another/the other tool?

Tags: adjectives, pronouns

Which one is correct:

1. If one tool of the kit is intended to be used in another one, then the description should have a reference to ANOTHER tool.
2. If one tool of the kit is intended to be used in another one, then the description should have a reference to THE OTHER tool.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one tool of the kit is intended to be used in another one, then the description should have a reference to **the other** tool.

*"the other"* because, the definite article indicates that the tool can be used in the other one, however the description of the same must be provided.

Another approach can be to use pronoun *that*.

> If one tool of the kit is intended to be used in another one, then the description should have a reference to **that other** tool.

---

Another alternative that can be used for the above sentence is:

> If one tool of the kit is intended to be used in another one, then the description should have a reference to **that 'another'** tool.

This sentence is not really very formal to write in journals, projects or any study related purposes. However, it is idiomatic and can be used to emphasise the context while representing it to the reader. These type of sentences are common in stories or literary fictions. Also while reading out loud or saying this sentence in public, we should actually stress upon the word *another*, in order to indicate its emphasis.

Comment: Also possible is "that other tool". This is acceptable in formal usage.

Comment: True. Do you mind if I edit my answer with your suggestion included?

Comment: That's fine. Thank you for your courtesy.